# MySQL Stored Procedure parameter validation

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I'm wondering what the best practice is for return validation errors from a MySQL Stored Procedure to a PHP application.  I've seen both [Signals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) and strings being used, but I'm looking for a way to automatically process errors so they can be mapped to the forms` field.

For example, if I have a registration form, I need to make sure that the email doesn't already exist in the system. So I need the Stored Procedure to return a key => value ex. `"email" => "Duplicate entry for email"`

I'm also thinking that it might not make sense to store the messages (that will be sent to the client) in the database.  Going off the email example above, `"email" => "1062"`, then inside the PHP application, have a map, `1062 => "$key already exists."`

I would be nice to be able to keep the key => (value / error message) association so an AJAX response object could contain something like

*`// Http Status 400`*
`{
  "email": "Email already exists",
  "name": "Name is required"
}`

That way the key of email and name and be directly associated with their inputs of "name" and "email".

```
<form>
  <input name="name"/>
  <input name="email"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<?php
  $sanitizedInput = $_POST; //Pretend this data is actually sanitized.
  $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL registerUser(?, ?)");
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $sanitizedInput["name"]);
  $stmt->bindParam(2, $sanitizedInput["email"]);

  #Whats the best method for processing?
  try{
      if($stmt->execute()){

      }else{

      }
  }catch(PDOException $e){
     //I want to prevent doing string comparisons if possible
     //Signal example
     //It seems like this step could be automated and reused.
     //For example, if we allow a user to update their email address,
     //we could have the string 'Duplicate entry for email' in the
     //codebase twice, and it seems like the process could be easily broken.
     if($stmt->errorInfo[2] == 'Duplicate entry for email'){
        return array('email' => 'Email already exists');
     }
  }
?>

#SQL
signal sqlstate = '45000' set message_text = 'Duplicate entry for email'

 create procedure registerUser(
   name varchar(50),
   email varchar(50)
 )
 begin
 declare emailExists int(0);

 select count(*) into emailExists from users where email = email;

 if emailExists = 0 then
     insert into users values(default, name, email);
 else
     //Return {email: 'Duplicate entry for email'}
 end
```

end

Answer (score 2):

Why would you run the validation in a stored procedure? why not use php to validate the format first. Then the second check would be this query

SELECT 1 FROM emails where email = 'abc@nb.com' LIMIT 1

if this query return 1 that mean the record exists?

if you want to use stored procedure which is an over kill here.

You can use `SQLEXCEPTION HANDLER`

something like this

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        @err_sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
        @err_message = MESSAGE_TEXT,
        @err_num = MYSQL_ERRNO;

        SET @hasError = TRUE;
    END;
```

After running a query you can do something like this

```
IF(@hasError)

 SELECT CONCAT("[",
      GROUP_CONCAT(
           CONCAT("{message:'", @err_message,"'"),
           CONCAT(",sqlState:'",@err_sqlstate),"'}")
      )
 ,"]") AS jSON
END IF;
```

Comment: Maybe validation was the wrong term,  the string format is checked within PHP, but other factors such and enforcing a single entry has to be done with SQL.  I'll update the stored procedure example to clairify my question.